# Explain variable declaration to a function in C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, recursion, cc

The following code is to calculate (base^pow)%mod

Can any one explain to me the following code which involves in declaring a variable to a function i want to know the value the function assigns to the variable and how it does it.

```
int tmp = mypow( base, pow >> 1, mod );
```

The whole code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int mypow( int base, int pow, int mod )
{
    if( pow == 0 ) return 1;
    if( pow % 2 == 0 ){
        int tmp = mypow( base, pow >> 1, mod );
    printf("\n\n%d\n\n",tmp);
        return tmp * tmp % mod;
    }
    else{
        return base * mypow( base, pow - 1, mod ) % mod;
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("\n\n%d\n\n", mypow(25,20,22));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a normal variable declaration with initialization. It's not different from e.g. `int tmp = 5;`, except that the initialization expression is a function call.

Comment: It's an implementation of the recursive algorithm described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method).

Answer (score 2):

The function will be executed with the given parameters, then it will `return()` the processed value. This value will then be assigned to the `var`.

```
int tmp = mypow( base, pow >> 1, mod );
```

This line is part of the recursive implementation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
int tmp = mypow( base, pow >> 1, mod );
```

This defines a variable named `tmp`, and initializes it to the value returned by function call `mypow( base, pow >> 1, mod )`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't called variable declaration to a function perhaps arguments passed to function.

So when you try calling a function as `mypow(25,20,22)`, these three actual args are passed to callee as formal arguments. In `C` you always do call by reference method in passing the args.